# Expo Crashing only on mobile, but works on Web output

Tags: reactjs, expo

I was working on a react native app on snack expo, and the app works fine on the web output viewer, but when I try to open it up on mobile, it either failsto load or more commonly crashes the Expo Go app. I am really confused because it does not throw any errors when it crashes, so any help or insight would be appreciated. Link: https://snack.expo.dev/@oofcraft/decrypter-2

Honestly, I didn't know what to try, since nothing was throwing any errors, but it should have worked on mobile.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with your style. in react native there is no use of `em` just pass the integer value

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabScreenButton: {
  textAlign:"center",
  marginTop:2,
  backgroundColor:"gray",
  padding:10,
  marginLeft: 5,
  marginRight: 5,
}
});
```